# How to copy array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to capture array instances in a function doSomething as Arrays in c++ are passed by reference  this is not possible .Is there any workaround to solve this problem!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int *A[10][10];

void doSomething(int ar[],int n){
    A[1][2] = ar;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        ar[i]+=1;
    }
    A[2][3] = ar;
}


int main(){
    int ar[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int n = 5;
    doSomething(ar,n);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<A[1][2][i]<<" "; // this should be 1 2 3 4 5 but output is 2 3 4 5 6 
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<A[2][3][i]<<" ";
    }

}
```

here first cout in main will print 2 3 4 5 6 but here I want output as 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: a) Stop using global variables like that. b) One possibility is to use std::vector (or std::array) instead of plain arrays. c) There are no references involded here. Just pointers, that are copied like all other (non-reference) function parameters.

Comment: why not to use std::array? You can pass it by val and by ref where you need it.

Comment: Remember that when you pass an array to a function it *decays* to a pointer (to its first element). That is, for argument function `int ar[]` is actually `int* ar`. Arrays are not passed by value.

Comment: As for a possible solution to your problem, I recommend you start using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  could you please share a link for quick reference.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: @hemant_ References for what? I already linked to a reference for `std::vector`. And if you browse around more on [that reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) you will found all the references you could ever ask for about C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 10>, 10>` or use a dedicated type like Boost's:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::multi_array<int, 3> A(boost::extents[10][10][5]);
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad97ce22ae37cf7b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using Array3d = boost::multi_array<int, 3>;
using Ref     = boost::const_multi_array_ref<int, 1>;
Array3d A{boost::extents[10][10][5]};

void doSomething(Ref const& ar) {
    A[1][2] = ar;
    A[2][3] = ar;
    for (auto& el : A[2][3]) el += 1;
}

template <typename Sub>
void dump(std::ostream& os, Sub const& ar) {
    std::copy(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
}

int main(){
    int ar[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    doSomething(Ref{ar, boost::extents[5]});

    dump(std::cout << "\nA[1][2] = ", A[1][2]);
    dump(std::cout << "\nA[2][3] = ", A[2][3]);
}
```

Which prints

```
A[1][2] = 1 2 3 4 5 
A[2][3] = 2 3 4 5 6
```

I guess for this simple case you could do with `std::vector<int> A[10][10]` though. Or even `std::array<int, 5> A[10][10]`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a9227c2d19f2f43)</kbd>**

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using Array5 = std::array<int, 5>;
Array5 A[10][10] {};

void doSomething(Array5 const& ar) {
    A[1][2] = ar;
    A[2][3] = ar;
    for (auto& el : A[2][3]) el += 1;
}

void dump(std::ostream& os, Array5 const& ar) {
    std::copy(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, " "));
}

int main(){
    doSomething({{1,2,3,4,5}});

    dump(std::cout << "\nA[1][2] = ", A[1][2]);
    dump(std::cout << "\nA[2][3] = ", A[2][3]);
}
```

Comment: Updated the samples to be a bit cleaner

Answer (score -1):

Don't use shitty C arrays- they are worthless. Use std::array/std::vector instead.